# Решение задачи рекурсивным методом. Проблема с некоторым выводом

Tags: c++, рекурсия, вывод

Всем добрый день! Есть задача: Роман состоит из C глав. Нужно, не переставляя главы, разбить его на B (В<С)
томов так, чтобы максимальная толщина тома (сумма количеств страниц
вошедших в него глав) была как можно меньше. Каждую главу начинают с
новой страницы, поэтому толщина тома есть сумма длин глав, входящих в него.
Разрывать главы нельзя. Если есть несколько равноценных оптимальных
решений, вывести любое из них.
10
Вход. В первой строке текста - количества С и В, в следующих С строках -
длины глав. 3≤В≤40, В≤С≤250, суммарное число страниц не больше 3x104.
Выход. В первой строке - максимальная толщина тома, в следующих В строках
- номера первой и последней глав каждого тома. Например, если пять глав
имеют длины 300, 300, 500, 300, 300 и распределяются по трем томам, то
максимальная толщина тома - 600, первый том начинается главой 1 и
заканчивается 2, второй включает только главу 3, третий - главы 4 и 5.

Сама функция есть и она работает, только я никак не могу додуматься, как сделать деление на главы? Код прикладываю ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int c, b;
vector<int>a, pref;

int Summ(int Start, int Finish)
{
    return pref[Finish + 1] - pref[Start];
}

int Razbienie(int begin, int end)
{
    if (end == 0)
    {
        return Summ(begin, c - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int m = 3e4;
        for (int i = begin + 1; i <= c - end; i++)
        {
            m = min(m, max(Razbienie(i, end - 1), Summ(begin, i - 1)));
        }
        return m;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "Введите количество глав и томов:"<<endl;
    cin >> c >> b;
    a.resize(c);
    pref.resize(c + 1);
    cout<< "Введите длину каждой главы:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        pref[i + 1] = pref[i] + a[i];
    }
    cout << "Максимальный размер тома - "<< Razbienie(0, b - 1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы не советовал основываться на таком коде.  Во вторых не ясно, что такое длина  главы, непонятно  что значит " границы томов, которые входят в каждый из томов"

Comment: Извините за ошибки. Другого кода к сожалению нет, поджимают сроки( У нас есть допустим 10 глав одной истории (в них сколько то слов), их нужно разделить на 4 тома. Нужно с помощью рекурсии сначала найти максимальное количество слов в одном томе (главное - нельзя делить главы), а затем распределить главы на каждый том по порядку. Как я указал в примере.

Comment: а почему пераый том не может содержать  больше одной главы?  И  вопрос не только в этом.  Но в общем вам наверное нужно где то хранить длины каждой главы и  начинать разбирать все возможные варианты.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan необходимо сделать размер тома минимальным, но так, чтобы все тома были одинакового размера и все главы были распределены по томам. Ещё раз исправил описание, полностью скопировав задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `Razbienie` у Вас фактически заполняет двумерную таблицу размером `BxC` (в явном виде она не хранится, только как локальные переменные рекурсивной функции).

Чтобы вернуть само разбиение, нужно завести таблицу переходов, использовать свои условия вместо библиотечных `min/max` функций, и в зависимости от выполняемой ветви if-оператора запоминать в каждой ячейке таблицы, откуда в неё пришли.

После нахождения лучшего разбиения пройти из конечной ячейки по запомненным переходам.